# Taking user input and adding it an array

Tags: java, arrays

My program uses an array: `collection[]` to hold information on cars. user input is used to add a car to the array using the console. So the user would enter the car's name, year of make, etc. However when it gets added to the array it goes straight into `collection[0]`. So if there is anything already in `collection[0]` it will replace it.

I want the user input to be but into the the next `null` cell in the array to avoid this problem. I have tried to write code that goes through each cell of the array and once it finds a cell which is `null` it then adds the information into it. However it is not working.

```
public void addCarInput1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)

    if (this.collection[i] = null) 
    {
        this.collection[i].addCarInput();
    }
}
```

Here is a shortened version of `addCarInput`:

```
Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter car make: ");
Cmake = sin.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter car model : ");
Mname = sin.nextLine();
```

Comment: How is collection defined? How is Cmake defined? How is Mname defined? Also in you if statement `if(collection[i] = null)` I think you want `==` instead of `=`. Also as a convention, instance names are supposed to start with lowercase letters to prevent confusion with class names.

Comment: Also ensure your array is large enough before adding anything to it. This seems like homework, but it is usually easier to use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you want more cars

```
String shouldContinue = null;
while(true) {
    if (shouldContinue.equals("no")) break;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter car make: ");
    String make = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter car model : ");
    String model = sc.nextLine();

    //add car info
    addCarInput(make, model);

    System.out.print("Enter info for another car? : ");
    shouldContinue = sc.nextLine()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a LinkedList or an ArrayList object instead of an array?
the add() method will add the elements at the end of the list & not replace the old values

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-in-java-example-how-to-use-arraylist/